# Combine Catalog Price Rule and cart price rule

Tags: cart, price, catalog

In Magento 2, I want to use a catalog price rule and exclude the Cart Price Rules.
For example, I want to add 10% discount in some products and the user couldn't use a coupon code for extra discount.
Any advice? If this has been asked before please advise.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

In your cart price rule add an action condition that is the opposite of your catalog price rule condition.

For example if your catalog price rule is add 10% discount to all product from category A. In your Cart Price rule Add an Action condition to specify that it should not apply to products in category A.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: But, is there are any solution? Because we have a lot products with different end dates and it is not possible to apply the exclusion.